# layout_weight on Android 2.3 does not work as expected

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-2.3-gingerbread, android-layout-weight

I use following Layout with weights and in the preview and on my Android 4 mobile everything works fine.

Now on my Android 2.3.4 mobile, instead of seeing 3 buttons and a spinner, I only see exactly 1 and a half button, the rest is not on the screen anymore...

If I change the last weight to 1, so that all views have a `layout_weight` of 1, it works on the old phone as well.

What do I do wrong?

Here is my code:

```
 <com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsLinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/illBottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btSelectAll"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/abs__item_background_holo_dark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:padding="4dip"
        android:src="@drawable/holo_dark_content_select_all" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btDeselectAll"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/abs__item_background_holo_dark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:padding="4dip"
        android:src="@drawable/holo_dark_custom_content_deselect_all" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btDeleteSelected"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/abs__item_background_holo_dark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:padding="4dip"
        android:src="@drawable/holo_dark_content_discard" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spData"
        style="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2" />
</com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsLinearLayout>
```

Comment: I notice you're using ActionBarSherlock but can you set orientation of the `LinearLayout` to horizontal? Usually you specify the orientation to go with the parameter that you give 0dp.

Comment: you're right... just tried it, but that did not solve my problem

Comment: why did you set layout_weight="2" to the spinner. usually, if You want to set on view bigger than the others,it will be a better practise to take a sum of for example 1. So split the values, for example for other views set 0.2 and spinner 0.4.

Comment: it does not matter, if I use relations like 1:1:1:2 or 0.2:0.2:0.2:0.4... Android will handle that automatically... But actually, I even tried that already with no success...

Comment: Are you using custom images? Is it possible the image size is what's affecting the distribution of the buttons? `layout_weight` only allocates excess px it does not change the size necessarially.

Comment: I'm using custom images... in hdpi/mdpi/xhdpi format... just the same sizes as the default holo theme on android 4 uses for action bar images... and in the resulting wring weighted output on my android 2.3.4 mobile, the image has the correct size for the screen, the height of the container is correct as well... just the weights don't work if they are not the same for all elements...

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you need to add a linear layout over the whole thing or use your already made com.... And put android:layout_weightSum="3 or whatever"

Put this into whatever element holds your image buttons.